# Bootstrap panel overlaying a previous div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code where I want to add 2 buttons and then bellow the buttons should be a bootstrap panel with options.

```
<div ng-controller="stdFormCtrl">

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <span class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Add</a>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default ">Preview</a>
    </span>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default ">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Options</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <select class="form-control" 
          ng-model="itemData.itemType" 
          ng-click="lstComponentSelected( )">
          [CODE CONTINUES]
```

The issue I am having, and I dont understand why, is that the panel heading stretch and include the buttons, so it seems like the Ädd"and "Preview" buttons are part of the headers instead

Can you please help me understand why this is happening, and how the buttons can be separated from the panel-header as I need to do?

Fiddle link as suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielBarcia/842hjam1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your code to https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the col-xs-12 to a row.

E.g.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Add</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default ">Preview</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: bootstrap floats columns, so if they are not contained within a row you will get the behaviour you experienced.

Comment: Thanks! Now that you explained it, I can see it clearly on the documentation.